# Parsing Javascript Objects in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to parse Javascript object definitions using Objective C.

Note that I'm NOT deserialising JSON. I need to parse bits of actual javascript source code. For example, something like this:

```
{ name : "Peter", phone : "" }
```

Note that unlike JSON, the 'name' and 'phone' don't have to be in quotes. This causes NSJSONSerialisation to fail immediately, so pretending that it's just JSON isn't going to work.

I don't suppose anyone has a solution that doesn't involve me writing an entire parser?

Comment: Well it looks like JSON, so perhaps investigate why `NSJSONSerialisation` is failing?

Comment: There are several open source JSON parsers for Objective-C, and it should be relatively easy to modify one of those for this (if your requirements are not much more than what's stated).  And some JSON parsers have various forms of "lenient" modes that may accept this.

Comment: @trojanfoe - As he said, there are no quotes on the keynames.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [JavascriptCore](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3784-javascriptcore-and-ios-7/) (though is iOS7+ / OSX10.5+)

Comment: @HotLicks Modifying 'JSON Framework' did the trick, thanks for the suggestion. Shame you didn't post that as an anwser instead...

Comment: I hate giving straight answers -- I always like to have some wiggle room.